# focus is changed to another window instead of android studio in debug time

Tags: android-studio, debugging, android-studio-3.3

when i updated android studio to version 3.3 whenever it is caught break point in debug mode,focus is changed to another window instead of android studio in Ubuntu

Comment: I have the same ridiculous problem